# How can i achieve telerik radorgchart vertically instead of growing horizantle

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad

I'am using telerik radorgchart for organization chart but on expansion of all the nodes it was growing horizantle. I wanted to grow vertical instead of horizantle. 
i wanted something like this [vertical orgchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhz6v.jpg).suggest me how can i acheive it.

Comment: `<telerik:RadOrgChart runat="server" ID="RadOrgChart1" RenderMode="Lightweight" Orientation="Vertical"` A simple Look at the documentation / demo of RadOrgChart  or a try on google would have give you the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadOrgChart's `Orientation` functionality is very useful when you want to control how the nodes are arranged and displayed on the page.
 Setting the RadOrgChart's `Orientation` property to `Horizontal` expands all Nodes horizontally.

This feature is available only if the control's `RenderMode` is set to `"Lightweight"`.

#### Related Resources

Review the following topic from the online documentation for more details:

- [RadOrgChart Horizontal Orientation.](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/orgchart/functionality/horizontal-orientation)

Your question was about `Vertical` Orientation. But actually it's the default Orientation.
So you should read the code you have copy-pasted because it obviously contains a `Orientation="Horizontal"`